# OpenGL-ES: how to draw object twice using different shaders

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, glsl

Im trying to make an app that simulates dice rolls, at the moment everything works fine. Im trying to add a shader for when the user selects a dice, it will put an outline around the selected dice. How im going about this is to render the particular dice scaled up slightly and completely black, then draw the textured dice on top of it to make it look like it has an outline.

The problem im having is that when the shader for drawing the object black is first applied, it draws the black dice fine, but when the textured dice is trying to be drawn over it, it draws it in the wrong place, and draws the wrong dice. The odd thing is it draws it inside one of the other dice on the screen.

If I apply the the same shader to the object twice, everything draws how its supposed to for that particular shader (either all black because of the outline shader or all textured and lit from the normal shader), but when I apply both shaders to the same model, things go wrong.

This class loads the vertices and stuff, and draws the object:
http://pastebin.com/N5aYAtBC

This class manages the shaders:
http://pastebin.com/0bT7ABRu

I've left out a lot of code that I feel will have nothing to do with the problem, but if you need more just leave a comment

and when i click on different dice this is what happens (first pic is normal):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWImo.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(toon_mvp, 1, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glUniform4fv(toon_outline, 1, oc);
glUseProgram(Toon);
```

I think you're handling the uniforms wrong. I pulled out this snippet from your source as an example.

When you upload a uniform, it only effects the currently bound program (each program has it's own internal storage of uniforms).

If you're expecting 'toon_mvp' and 'toon_outline' to be available to the program 'Toon', they will not be. You need to first bind the program you want to modify, and then modify it's uniforms after it is bound, not in the other order.

You'll probably have to fix this in other places in your code as well.

Comment: Also: don't forget that different programs use different uniform locations. So you have to keep a set of uniform locations for each program.

Comment: thanks for the replies, I will try this out as soon as I can and report back

Comment: Ok this worked, I moved the glUseProgram to the top of the method and it fixed it, for the most part... Im having a problem now that it doesnt render the right model for the outline shader now, well for some. The 10 sided dice work perfectly, while the rest seem to get mixed up which model to use, so like the 6 sided dice will have the outline of the 8 sided dice etc. Cant figure out why, will need to prod around some more, but maybe there is a clue in the code that someone with more knowledge than I do will pick up.